# "Unable to locate package ros-diamondback/electric-nxtall"

Tags: nxt, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My name is Noah and I am a novice programmer looking to use ROS with the NXT Lego robotics kits. I succeeded in installing the generic ROS and am partway through the beginner tutorials even. However, I recently tried to install the ROS NXT release and received the error message in the title. The first thing I realized was that there doesn't seem to be an NXT package for Fuerte, although I don't know if that is an issue for sure. However, I have tried the main ROS server as well as each of the mirrors and cannot locate any of the NXT packages even though looking through the mirrors manually I can even see the packages that I am looking for. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

EDIT: **Also using a Virtual Machine (VirtualBox) running Ubuntu Precise 12.04 LTS and ROS Fuerte.** The command I tried running was:

sudo apt-get install ros-electric-nxtall (also tried for diamondback)

Which returned the following:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-electric-nxtall

I think what I'm going to try to do is just removing this VM and reinstalling with something like Ubuntu 10.04 and getting ROS Electric, which as far as I can tell will definitely work. I just wanted to avoid doing so as my internet connection is relatively slow and I'd like to avoid wasting the several hours I spent setting ROS up. Oh well though; I guess that's the life of a programmer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37089/%22unable-to-locate-package-ros-diamondback/electric-nxtall%22/) by [Nezteb](https://answers.ros.org/users/2691/nezteb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2012-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-06-22**:
Please post the exact command you ran, along with the exact error message you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Debs pre-Fuerte are not available on 12.04. Installing 10.04 like you mentioned will certainly do the trick.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1